# Jquery Easy UI DataGridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-easyui

I have two questions
1.I have this code that the grid view doesnt show the data. (When I create new project (nonempty,WebForms) it works but in this project it doesnt)
I'll ask the next question later
Cs File

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    [WebMethod(true)]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static string GetCustomers()
    {
        List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        Dictionary<string, object> data = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        Dictionary<string, object> row;


        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            row.Add("ID", i.ToString());
            row.Add("FirstName", "Name" + i.ToString());
            row.Add("LastName", "LastName" + i.ToString());
            row.Add("Age", i.ToString());
            rows.Add(row);
        }
        data.Add("total", 10);

        data.Add("rows", rows);

        System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        return serializer.Serialize(data);
    }
}
```

Aspx File

```
 <table class="easyui-datagrid" title="Basic DataGrid" style="width:700px;height:250px"
            data-options="singleSelect:true,collapsible:true,url:'<%= ResolveUrl("Default.aspx/GetCustomers") %>',method:'post'">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-options="field:'ID',width:80">Item ID</th>
                <th data-options="field:'FirstName',width:100">FirstName</th>
                <th data-options="field:'LastName',width:80,align:'right'">LastName</th>
                <th data-options="field:'Age',width:80,align:'right'">Age</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

Comment: Hey I'm still waiting for your help.

Comment: I can use ajax like this

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function FillGridView() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "WebForm1.aspx/GetCustomers",
            }).done(function (loaded) {
                jQuery('#dateGrid1').datagrid({
                    data: eval(loaded.d)
                });
            });
        });
    </script>